# Retrieving foreach loop values in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have values in the listbox from which I have to select one or more values and save it in the database. But when I select more than one value (ex: 2 items selected) it is only saving the first value of the items I have selected (ex: twice).

Here is the query to save in the database.

```
foreach (ListItem li in lbMess.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected)
    {
        strSQL += string.Format("INSERT INTO message(messageContent, messageDate, staffCode) VALUES ('{0}',getdate(),'{1}');", txtMess.Text, lbMess.SelectedValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you're accessing items from within a foreach loop, you can't retrieve the data you want from the Control itself, you have to access the data from the variable that you declared in the `foreach(ListItem li...` For example, if you say "Get me the values of all selected items in this control" - Where will you store those values? You'd store them in a variable, right? So in your case, that variable is `li`. So to access the SelectedItem data, you'd do something like: `foreach(ListItem li in lbMess.Items) {  string data = li.Text; }`

Answer (score 4):

In your insert statement you aren't using the `li` you are iterating.

Try this:

```
strSQL += string.Format("INSERT INTO message(messageContent,messageDate,staffCode) VALUES ('{0}',getdate(),'{1}');", txtMess.Text, li.Text);
```

Comment: @mujtaba: Do you need more help? If any of the answers were sufficient, please don't forget to mark your question answered by checking the checkmark before the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Youu are using `lbMess.SelectedValue` which by default will only get the first item, yet you are looping through all the items.

Make sure you use the value of the `li` object instead. (`li.Value` or `li.Text` depending on how you implemented it)

Answer (score 1):

> Youu are using lbMess.SelectedValue which by default will only get the
>   first item.

Try this

```
foreach (ListItem li in lbMess.Items)
{
   if (li.Selected)
   {
     strSQL += string.Format("INSERT INTO message(messageContent,messageDate,staffCode) VALUES ('{0}',getdate(),'{1}');", txtMess.Text, li.Value);
   }

 }
```

**OR:**

```
foreach (ListItem li in lbMess.Items)
{
   if (li.Selected)
   {
     strSQL += string.Format("INSERT INTO message(messageContent,messageDate,staffCode) VALUES ('{0}',getdate(),'{1}');", txtMess.Text, li.Text);
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should iterate the SelectedItems property, like so:

```
            foreach(var item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
            {
                // Insert into DB.
                strSQL += string.Format("INSERT INTO message(messageContent,
                messageDate,staffCode) VALUES ('{0}',getdate(),'{1}');", 
                    txtMess.Text, (String)item);
            }
```